# overriding shouldAutorotate not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, autorotate

I'm trying to prevent rotation on one `UIViewController` and I can't achieve that.

I'm doing something like this:

```
open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return false
    }
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

And the `UIViewControler` stills rotating. The UIViewController is inside a UINavigationController opened modally.

I have looked a lot of questions from here and none answers works for me.

In Swift 2 I used to override `shouldAutorotate` but in Swift 3 that function doesn't exist anymore.

How can I do that in Swift 3 what I used to do in Swift 2?

Comment: What does your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` look like?

Comment: @matt I edited the question adding that

Comment: Thanks. Okay, so if this is a presented view controller, it should appear only in portrait and stay there. If that's not happening, there must be more to the story. Can you describe _how_ this view controller is presented? Prove to me that it is a fullscreen top-level presented view controller.

Comment: @matt The view controller is presented modally via a bar button item tapped and the view controller is inside a navigation controller, I don't know if is not possible to prevent rotation on a modal view controller

Comment: If you present a view controller that itself is inside a navigation controller, that is not a presented view controller. The navigation controller is the presented view controller. So the problem would be that your view controller's settings here are irrelevant; it is the _navigation controller_ that is the presented view controller, so _it_ gets to determine the rotation (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: `shouldAutorotate` is still there, but instead of a function, it is now a `var`. And what you have in your code seems correct. I think Matt's suggestion is what you need ...

Comment: @matt thanks for the advise, I create a custom class for the NavigationController and I applied the functions I described from my question and it works

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't know why is a vote to close the question if I can reproduce this behavior a lots of times. The `UIViewController` is inside a `UINavigationController` opened modally.

This is what I did to solve the problem.

I create this class and I set to the `UINavigationController` that containt the `UIViewController` that I want to prevent to rotate

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController { 

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }

}
```

And thats it, it works for me

Comment: but what if you only want a specific UIViewController not to rotate and not the entire navigation stack? This answer seems like a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39805665

Comment: @RoyShilkrot It is ok, the goal of the question was how to prevent the rotation of one view controller inside a navigation controller, not how to prevent a specific view controller inside a entire navigation stack

Comment: Works nicely in conjunction with @Thuggish Nuggets observation below - so two upvotes

Comment: This did not work until checking `Requires full screen` in the `General` tab of the app. With that, the Thuggish Nuggets code above should not be necessary.

Comment: amazing great !

Answer (score 11):

Add this code to AppDelegate.swift

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}

struct AppUtility {
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Add to the viewcontroller that you want to force an orientation:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    //UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")


    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.landscapeLeft)

}
```

Comment: This works for me, but the accepted answer is much cleaner and also works. Is there a specific scenario where the accepted answer is not possible and only this works?

Comment: This works for me; the accepted answer wasn't working.

Comment: This works great for me; the best solution, the accepted answer wasn't working very well.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This works, but do you find the previous view controller will deinit() ?

Comment: While this solution might work, it uses a private API, which means it may break in future versions; plus, you may have problems with the App Store review guidelines.

Comment: As stated by @Vym, this method was prone to break in newer versions: in fact it did in 16.0. Using this solution now will fail.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the voted answer didn't work. Instead,

```
override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
}
```

Those codes work. Confirmed in Swift 4.

Answer (score 3):

I found that iOS 11 wasn't calling these methods at all unless I had implemented the following `UIApplicationDelegate` method in my `AppDelegate` class:

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?)
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 11, Swift 5**

The new secret sauce is to add this in viewDidLoad()

`UIDevice.current.setValue(self.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`

Also be sure to override preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation to return your preferred orientation:

`override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation : UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
}`

Found the answer here:
https://nunoalexandre.com/2018/08/24/forcing-an-orientation-in-ios

Comment: This method utilised a private API and was removed in iOS 16.0. Using this solution now will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Answer - this is how you do it now in 2022

```
@objcMembers class YourViewController: UIViewController
{
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { return true }
    ...
    init() {}
    ...
 }
```