# iOS 11 Device Orientation Autorotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, orientation, ios11

For **iOS 10** and below, the following code controlled the orientation of the any respective `UIViewController`. I have selected `Portrait`, `Landscape Left`, and `Landscape Right` in my Deployment Info, and have the following in my **Info.plist**:

[image]

For my VC's that should **not** rotate at all I have the following code, which I stated, was working prior **iOS 11**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    [super shouldAutorotate];
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I have tested this on actual devices and as of **iOS 11** it does not work.

Even more strangely, logging the registered device orientation as of **iOS 11** tells my the device **IS** portrait... when the controller loads in landscape mode...

Code:

```
// In viewDidLoad 
NSLog(@"orientation: %lu", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
```

Console output:

```
2017-09-22 15:20:26.225196-0400 <APP_NAME>[2669:1628408] orientation: 1
```

This occurs either rotating the device left or right before building and running the app.

---

- What is the cause here for this error? If anyone knows please help..

---

#### FYI: No, I do not have rotation lock on my device..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether this proves to be an **iOS 11** bug or not, I seemed to have stumbled upon a "solution" to this issue. For whatever reason, for **iOS 11** changing the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` return to `YES` allows for the correct orientation...

#### Objc

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    [super shouldAutorotate];
    
    if (@available(iOS 11, *)) return YES;
    return NO;

}
```

In combination I had to do a manual check for the screen dimensions to see if the width was greater or less than the supposed height of the screen.

```
width = self.view.frame.size.width, height = self.view.frame.size.height;
if (height < width) width = height, height = self.view.frame.size.width;
```

Hopefully someone else finds the true cause of this "bug" **OR** Apple updates their bundle to handle rotations like all previous iOS versions..

#### Swift 3.2+

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // Anything else iOS 11 specific
        return true
    } 
    return false

}
```

Comment: On iOS 11.2 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {} is not called at all. Not in the root view controller, nor in later view controllers.

Comment: Create a navigation controller and call this method there if your VC is not calling - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413567/overriding-shouldautorotate-not-working-in-swift-3

Comment: I found that iOS 11 wouldn't call any of these methods until I had implemented `application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?)` in my `UIApplicationDelegate` class.